# How to construct 4 external lines Feynman diagram from 3 external lines Feynman diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

From [Renormalization talk/idea](https://youtu.be/Nm8DRUgmjZc) by Sean Carroll, when he talks about *effective field theory*:

> but then I could construct from that the following diagram with four
> lines in it
> [image]

In previous talks he explained a bit about diagrams and told interactions can be represented by many (even infinite) number of diagrams. Additionally he mentions "in" lines can be changed to "out" ones (anti-particle), but for one particular interaction, the number of external lines remains the same. Above he claims to construct a 4 external legs interaction from a 3 one. What does it mean?

ADDED more context from the video:

> let's imagine you only had Phi cubed in your field theory that would lead to a Feynman diagram that is just this little vertex but then I could construct from that the following diagram with four lines in it... so for the effective field theorist you don't have a choice when you start writing down terms in your Lagrangian you have to include them all as long as they don't violate some symmetry or something

Comment: What is an "in+out line"?

Comment: @NiharKarve I think he means “in or out” as in 4 external lines. Looks like Carroll is showing something about the effective potential.

Comment: Imagine cutting each side of that box, you'd then have four copies of your three legged diagram.

Comment: @Triatticus, indeed looks like it. Why do you think it is what Sean refers to?

Comment: @kaylimekay, thank you. I've edited the question to make it more "correct".

Comment: Well the terms in the progression at the top refer to different vertexes, and you won't get a box diagram from any of them unless you put the basic vertexes together.

Comment: @ Triatticus, maybe I better edit the question again to add more info from the talk. The flow of cause-effect is inverse.

Comment: @Triatticus, "basic vertexes". What is it? I could not find it to be some established term.